# Explain into disjunctive normal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

Can anyone tell me how to Express the following formula into disjunctive normal form ⌐ (p V q) ↔ (p ^ q). I have done few steps but I need your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

A DNF is an OR of ANDS.

$\neg (p\lor q) \leftrightarrow (p\land q)$
$(\neg p\land \neg q) \leftrightarrow (p \land q)$
$((\neg p\land \neg q) \to (p \land q))\land ((p \land q) \to (\neg p\land \neg q))$
$(\neg(\neg p\land \neg q) \lor (p \land q))\land (\neg(p \land q) \lor (\neg p\land \neg q))$
$(p\lor q) \lor (p \land q)\land ((\neg p\lor \neg q) \lor (\neg p\land \neg q))$

Now, just distribute and simplify.